# Implementing Signal R in android

Tags: android, signalr

I have tried in following way,

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.LogLevel;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Logger;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.Platform;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.SignalRFuture;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.http.android.AndroidPlatformComponent;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.HubConnection;
import microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client.hubs.HubProxy;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;

public class HomeActivity2 extends Activity {
    /**
     * shared preference for access temp storage
     */
    private SharedPreferences settings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        settings = getSharedPreferences(Utils.PREFS_NAME, 0);
        Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
        String host = "MyURL";
        String CONNECTION_QUERYSTRING = "ClientID="
                + settings.getString("clientID", "") + "&RoleID="
                + settings.getString("roleID", "") + "&UserID="
                + settings.getString("employeeID", "");
        HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(host,
                Base64.encodeToString(CONNECTION_QUERYSTRING.getBytes(),
                        Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP), false, new Logger() {

                    @Override
                    public void log(String message, LogLevel level) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println(message);
                    }
                });
        HubProxy hub = connection.createHubProxy("NotificationHub");
        SignalRFuture<Void> awaitConnection = connection.start();
        try {
            awaitConnection.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Logcat trace

```
HubConnection - Creating hub proxy: notificationhub
HubConnection - Entered startLock in start
HubConnection - Start the connection, using AutomaticTransport transport
HubConnection - Start negotiation
AutomaticTransport - Start the negotiation with the server
HubConnection - Getting connection data: [{"name":"notificationhub"}]
HubConnection - Getting connection data: [{"name":"notificationhub"}]
AutomaticTransport - Execute the request
Create new thread for HTTP Connection
Execute the HTTP Request
URL: http://citrusz.com/notification/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.3&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D&Q2xpZW50SUQ9Q0xOVEFBQUEwMDAxJlJvbGVJRD1ST0xFQUFBQTAwMDEmVXNlcklEPUVNUEFBQUEwMDAz
VERB: GET
Header User-Agent: SignalR (lang=Java; os=android; version=2.0)
CONTENT: null
Request executed
AutomaticTransport - Response received
AutomaticTransport - Read response data to the end AutomaticTransport - Trigger onSuccess with negotiation data: {"Url":"/notification/signalr","ConnectionToken":"SYqo8IyKwjb1zqPzDkPuVsMSrqgDmaQASB0Jirr1yUXRW698WbS8cM0BYuHdFQIEtQf5IYenCNp+1KV2EwUF7QOAcyaLbI4ohLiGKvf2umGn6+dbitwZcKLwjSCgJfpo","ConnectionId":"41c2e849-756f-4cb9-90fc-2688fdbbb619","KeepAliveTimeout":20.0,"DisconnectTimeout":30.0,"TryWebSockets":false,"ProtocolVersion":"1.3","TransportConnectTimeout":5.0}
HubConnection - Negotiation completed
HubConnection - ConnectionId: 41c2e849-756f-4cb9-90fc-2688fdbbb619
HubConnection - ConnectionToken: SYqo8IyKwjb1zqPzDkPuVsMSrqgDmaQASB0Jirr1yUXRW698WbS8cM0BYuHdFQIEtQf5IYenCNp+1KV2EwUF7QOAcyaLbI4ohLiGKvf2umGn6+dbitwZcKLwjSCgJfpo
HubConnection - Keep alive timeout: 20.0
HubConnection - Entered startLock in startTransport
HubConnection - Starting the transport
GC_CONCURRENT freed 620K, 12% free 6348K/7175K, paused 3ms+3ms
HubConnection - Starting transport for InitialConnection
serverSentEvents - Start the communication with the server
HubConnection - Getting connection data: [{"name":"notificationhub"}]
serverSentEvents - Execute the request
Create new thread for HTTP Connection
Execute the HTTP Request
URL: http://citrusz.com/notification/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionToken=SYqo8IyKwjb1zqPzDkPuVsMSrqgDmaQASB0Jirr1yUXRW698WbS8cM0BYuHdFQIEtQf5IYenCNp%2B1KV2EwUF7QOAcyaLbI4ohLiGKvf2umGn6%2BdbitwZcKLwjSCgJfpo&connectionId=41c2e849-756f-4cb9-90fc-2688fdbbb619&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D&Q2xpZW50SUQ9Q0xOVEFBQUEwMDAxJlJvbGVJRD1ST0xFQUFBQTAwMDEmVXNlcklEPUVNUEFBQUEwMDAz
VERB: GET
Header Accept: text/event-stream
Header User-Agent: SignalR (lang=Java; os=android; version=2.0)
CONTENT: null
Request executed
threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

I think SignalR is connected, But my android Screen is full black, if I comment `awaitConnection.get();` app works fine, I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help will be highly appreciable

Thanks, Guna

Comment: Having the same issue at:
HubConnection - Getting connection data: [{"name":"notificationhub"}]
Locks entire app process..

Answer (score 4):

It's hanging as you are making the connection synchronous by calling 'get()'.

I faced a similar issue and in my case it was an issue with WebSockets and had to fall back to using ServerSentEvents.

```
HubProxy hub = connection.createHubProxy("NotificationHub")
ClientTransport transport = new ServerSentEventsTransport(connection.getLogger());

SignalRFuture<Void> awaitConnection = connection.start(transport);
try {
    awaitConnection.get();
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to double-check your development environment to ensure that WebSockets are supported. Android devices support WebSocket; however, your server might not.

WebSockets began to be supported in IIS 8 on Windows 8/Server 2012 and higher.

**Your options are:**

- For local development & testing, use at least Visual Studio 2013 on
  Windows 8.1.
- For production, use at least Windows Server 2012*
  with IIS 8.

**To enable the feature, you may need to go to Windows Roles & Features -> Web
    Server -> Application Development -> Install WebSockets.*

Comment: "only windows server 2012 upper and iis8 upper support websocket and too win8 local host iisexpress" this is not correct